# How to limit the number of cores of CPU used?

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, machine-learning, cpu

I am trying to use only single core of CPU. My system has 8 Cores. When I `htop` on terminal it should use only single core else all should remain silent. I am using below code but it is still using my all cores, what am I doing wrong ?

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

session_conf =  tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, 
                               inter_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                               device_count={'CPU': 1})

sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf)
```

It is utilizing all cores but with low percentage like 23 or 20 etc!

Comment: That's normal; CPU migrations happen sometimes, e.g. when an interrupt handler on one CPU runs long enough for the scheduler on another core to decide to run the task that's waiting for a CPU.  A good OS like Linux will typically avoid bouncing a task around too much because caches and branch predictors on the previous CPU were hot with its data.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention htop I assume you are in a linux system.

You can try to start your script using [taskset](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html), if your process start other processes you may want to set CPU affinity for each of them, by `taskset -p <mask> <pid>`.